# get data from java into java script

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, graph

I am trying to plot a graph using a java script library, I am getting data into java as List of string(List). List contain a string followed by 3 floats, a string and 3 floats and so on.. How can I get these value in java scripts and convert them into strings and floats. Thank you

Edit : I am getting data from database into a jsp page as List of String. I am using floatchart library so in java script it accepts the data like this :

```
data: [[1988, 483994], [1989, 479060], [1990, 457648], [1991, 401949], [1992, 424705], [1993, 402375], [1994, 377867], [1995, 357382], [1996, 337946], [1997, 336185], [1998, 328611], [1999, 329421], [2000, 342172], [2001, 344932], [2002, 387303], [2003, 440813], [2004, 480451], [2005, 504638], [2006, 528692]]
```

I did some thing like this in PHP, first I got all the data in a div as comma separated mark up, and then i got the content of div element in java script, split the content by ',' , and used Number to convert string to float.

```
     var see = document.getElementById('sentimentBox').innerHTML;
     var posneg = see.split(",");
```

Number(posneg[i]) will have the values.

Comment: You can get the data by introducing some code. We would like to see what code have you tried?

Comment: My initial thought would be to serialize your java objects into json and just use that in your javascript, but without looking at your specific use-case, I can't be sure.

Comment: Where is the Java running, and where is the Javascript running? Are they both part of some weird Node.js setup? Are you trying to retrieve it on a webpage? Javascript normally runs in an entirely different program from Java, so the question seems to be worded strangely.

Comment: my mistake i should have mentioned jsp instead of java.